# how can I create different attribute set for different category in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes

How can I create different attributes for different category in Magento.
For example I have categories like Paints and tiles. Since these two are entirely different product category, the attributes will also be different. how can I set different attribute for this. Please suggest me the best method to do this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute sets with attributes relates to the categories through the product. Cause the product has relations with a attribute set
[image]

and the categories

[image]

There isn't required to do any additional customizations. Just create a required attribute sets and take a look at the categories that assigned to the product.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute sets and categories are 2 distinct entities in Magento.
the attribute sets are in a 1 to many relation with products. This means that you can create as many products as you want associated to an attribute set.
And the products are in a many to many relation with the categories. This means you can associate as many categories as you want to a product and as many products as you want to a category.
What you can do is to create your "Paints" attribute set and create as many products as you need in that attribute set.
Then you can create the Paints category and assign all the products in the Paints attribute set to the category.

Comment: Is it the same with Magento 2.X ?

Comment: Yes it is the same